# Subclassing List and Jackson JSON serialization

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have a small POJO, containing an ArrayList (`items`), a String (`title`), and an Integer (`id`). Due to the fact that this is an Object, I have to a) implement my own wrapping methods around the List interface methods for the "items" property or b) make `items` public (lots of stuff happens with that list).

**Edit:** to make the above point clearer, I need to access the List after deserialisation
to perform add/remove/get/etc operations - which means I either need to write wrapping methods in my class or make the List public, neither of which I want to do.

In order to avoid this, I want to just directly extend ArrayList, however I can't seem to get it to work with Jackson. Given some JSON like this:

```
{ "title": "my-title", "id": 15, "items": [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
```

I want to deserialize `title` into the `title` field, likewise for `id`, however I want to then populate my class with that of `items`.

Something that looks like this:

```
public class myClass extends ArrayList<Integer> {

    private String title;
    private Integer id;

    // myClass becomes populated with the elements of "items" in the JSON

}
```

I attempted several ways at implementing this and all fell down, even things such as:

```
private ArrayList<Integer> items = this; // total long shot
```

Is what I am trying to accomplish simply something which cannot be done with Jackson?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could the following pattern be of use?

- The `@JsonCreator` neatly creates your object as specified by the provided JSON.
- The properties are specified via `@JsonProperty` annotations - work for both serialization and deserialization
- you can inherit the `ArrayList` as per your requirements

The *magic* lies in specifying the `@JsonFormat` on the first line. It instructs the object mapper to **NOT** treat this object as a collection or array - simply treat it as an Object.

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.OBJECT)
public class MyList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    private final Integer id;
    private final String title;

    @JsonCreator
    public MyList(@JsonProperty("id") final Integer id,
                  @JsonProperty("title") final String title,
                  @JsonProperty("items") final List<Integer> items) {
        super(items);
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Integer id() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonProperty("items")
    public Integer[] items() {
        return this.toArray(new Integer[size()]);
    }

    @JsonProperty("title")
    public String title() {
        return title;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ooooo, nice! I had something similar to this but I had no idea about `@JsonFormat`. I'll give the above a shot and report back.

Comment: this worked perfectly, thanks for the tip on `@JsonFormat`, I've never see it used before/when browsing the docs.